# Profiling fastAPI endpoint with pyinstrument

Tags: python, profiling, fastapi

I am trying to profile my fastapi endpoints with pyinstrument. After some searching online I see that starting from pyinstrument 4.0 there is async support.

When using the code snippet provided in the documentation of Pyinstrument:

```
from pyinstrument import Profiler


PROFILING = True  # Set this from a settings model

if PROFILING:
    @app.middleware("http")
    async def profile_request(request: Request, call_next):
        profiling = request.query_params.get("profile", False)
        if profiling:
            profiler = Profiler(interval=settings.profiling_interval, async_mode="enabled")
            profiler.start()
            await call_next(request)
            profiler.stop()
            return HTMLResponse(profiler.output_html())
        else:
            return await call_next(request)
```

I see a nice callstack appear when calling an endpoint, however as soon as the actual (synchronous) code is run, I only see `[await]` in the stack trace...

[image]

Putting the `Profiler` inside the code that is being executed within the endpoints solves the issue, but I have many endpoints and would like a solution that is more generic.

Comment: Hey @Erik any chance you found a solution to this?

Comment: @TravisChambers unfortunately not. I decided to handle a couple of slow endpoints manually and then just moved on.

Comment: That's too bad. In the meantime, I've run across yappi - https://github.com/sumerc/yappi. I can't seem to get that nice callstack output, but it _does_ show information for async calls.

Comment: Some more info I found on yappi's github - https://github.com/joerick/pyinstrument/issues/219#issuecomment-1291239186

Comment: Haven't tried it but saw this thread - https://github.com/joerick/pyinstrument/issues/128
Any chance passing in the show_all argument would work out here?